# C# 7.0 Tuple Deduction

Tags: c#, tuples, c#-7.0

When I write this line:

```
Tuple<string,string> key = (controller, action);
```

I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type '(string controller,
>   string action)' to 'System.Tuple'  Project.Web PageMetadata.cs 27  Active

This seems like a fairly straight-forward, intuitive application of the new tuple enhancements that are at the heart of the C#7 updates, and yet it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new tuples features require the [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2?view=netframework-4.7) type i.e.

```
ValueTuple<string, string> key = (controller, action);
```

or

```
var key = (controller, action);
```

it's important to note that a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=netframework-4.7) is a class and [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2?view=netframework-4.7) is a struct. you should not mix them up. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples) for more details about the new tuple features in C# 7.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you get that error as you are trying to cast the new style tuple (`ValueTuple`) to the old style tuple (`Tuple`).

This can be achieved using the `ToTuple()` extension method:

```
Tuple<string,string> key = (controller, action).ToTuple();
```

But that probably isn't what you are trying to do. If you want to create an instance of a new tuple, you could do:

```
ValueTuple<string,string> key = (controller, action);
```

But if you do that, you still end up with the two elements being called `Item1` and `Item2`, which defeats one of the key features of the new tuple syntax: named elements. Change it to use `var`, and you then get named elements:

```
var key = (controller, action);
Console.WriteLine(key.controller); // key.controller is now valid
```

If you really don't like using `var` (some folk do not), then you can express it longhand to still get those named elements:

```
(string controller, string action) key = (controller, action); 
Console.WriteLine(key.controller);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ValueTuple<string, string>` instead of `Tuple<string, string>`. [`Tuple<T1,T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=netframework-4.7.1) is a system type from before C# 7.0; [`ValueTuple<T1,T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2?view=netframework-4.7.1) is the one that supports the new language features. For more details, see [the C# Tuple type guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to convert from `System.Tuple` to `System.ValueTuple` (used by tuple syntax), or back, there are extension methods: `ToTuple` and `ToValueTuple` defined for small arities.